# Is there an English translation of Hadamard's classic French paper on well-posed problems?

Tags: reference-request, inverse-problems, translation

[This paper](https://hal.inria.fr/file/index/docid/241199/filename/ajp-jphystap_1907_6_202_0.pdf) by Hadamard is often cited as being the source of the definition of well-posed and ill-posed problems.

However, it is in French so I cannot verify that claim.

Is there an English translation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no "official" English translation, however, [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&tab=TT) should work just fine, here is the translation of the first paragraph, *without any corrections from my side*:

> The general question that we propose to study is the determination of
>   the solutions of a linear equation to the derivatives partial ones of
>   the second order (this is the case to which we shall confine
>   ourselves) by data at the limits. In other words, we have to summarize
>   the results obtained in relation to the following two questions:
>   1) What are the data required to determine a solution of a partial
>   differential equation?
>   2) How can we calculate the solution
>   according to the data provided?
>   These two questions are precisely
>   those which Mr. Poincaré his important discourse *On the Reports of
>   Pure Analysis and Mathematical Physics* (International Congress of
>   Mathematicians, Zurich, 1897), cited as an example of the aid which
>   Physics is capable of bringing to analysis. And, indeed, there is
>   perhaps no case in which the conclusion which he has developed is more
>   strikingly apparent:
>   • It is mathematical physics that shows us what
>   problems we must ask ourselves.
>   • It is also what makes us foresee
>   the solution.

(Incidentally, a nice description of how physics can help mathematics.)

---

Following a suggestion by Sylvain Jullien, I tried the translator at [DeepL.com](https://www.deepl.com/translator), on the same paragraph. Remarkably similar translation, actually, I presume they use pretty much the same neural network architecture as Google.

> The general question that we propose to study is the determination of
>   the solutions of a linear equation to derivatives partial second order
>   data (this is the case to which we will confine ourselves) with data
>   at the limits. In other words, we have to summarize the results
>   achieved with respect to the following two-pronged question:
>   1) What is
>   the evidence to determine a solution to an partial derivatives?
>   2) How
>   to calculate the solution based on data so provided?
>   These two
>   questions are precisely those which Mr Poincaré, in his important
>   discourse *On the reports of Pure Analysis and Mathematical Physics*
>   (International Congress of Mathematicians, Zurich, 1897) cited as an
>   example of the help that Physics is likely to bring to Analysis. And,
>   indeed, there may not be any case in which the conclusion that he came
>   to is more striking:
>   • It is mathematical physics that shows us which
>   problems we must face.
>   • It is also what makes us foresee the solution.

---

... and just for completeness, here is what [Microsoft Translator](https://www.bing.com/translator) produces (somewhat less to my liking):

> The general question we propose to study is the determination of the
>   solutions of a linear equation to the derivatives partial second order
>   (this is the case we will confine ourselves to) by data to the limits.
>   In other words, we have to sum up the results gained relativity to the
>   following double question:
>   1) What are the data to determine a solution
>   of a equation to partial derivatives?
>   2) How can the solution be
>   calculated according to of the data so provided?
>   These two questions
>   are precisely those that Mr. Poincaré, in his important speech on the
>   *Reports of Analyse pure and Mathematical physics* (International
>   Congress of Mathematicians, Zurich, 1897), cited as an example of the
>   aid that physics is likely to bring to the analysis. And, indeed,
>   there may be no cases in which more strikingly appears the conclusion
>   that it has developed:
>   • It is the mathematical physics that shows us
>   which problems we have to ask ourselves.
>   • She also makes us anticipate
>   the solution.

Comment: Otherwise deepl.com might provide a better result than Google translate.

Comment: good suggestion, I tried it.